# /usr mysteriously changed owner

Tags: permissions, security

Somehow my /usr directory had its ownership changed from root:root to <my username>:<my username>. I noticed this when I tried to use sudo, and got an error messaging saying it had to be owned by root.

I don't know how this could have happened, I have no chown commands in my bash history. The  most recent use of sudo I used was `sudo npm install -g <something>`. That's admittedly inadvisable, but I was really frustrated with trying to get something to work. Is this random permissions change a sign that my system is compromised somehow? Is there some other explanation for what could have happened?

Comment: Somehow running npm as sudo seems very wrong. Which JavaScript modules did you need to deploy, circumventing your Linux distro, as root?  The "which" might be a bit important, seeing that this might have messed up your machine. Also, hope you have a clear idea of the dependencies you pulled in - you just let them all execute code as root. (I can't tell you whether something is a *clear* indication of compromised system, but the fact that we *can't rule it out* is sufficient that if this system touches sensitive data like passwords or user information, it's time to restore it from backup)

Comment: The dependenceis were: argparse, http-proxy, js-beautify, jszip, koa, koa-conditional-ge, tnode-fetch. I didn't execute any code manually as root, so it would have had to have been during the installation process. Also this is a personal laptop so it _does_ touch user information, but I am the only user.

Comment: so yeah, I mean, as said I can't tell whether it's been compromised. I don't know koa but the rest seems benign enough. Again, we can't rule out compromise, so the *safe* thing is to *assume* compromise and lateral movement from your laptop using the credentials stored on your laptop. It's however not a sure or necessarily even a likely thing. We're in the deep waters of thread modelling, which we can't do for you.

Comment: *threat, not thread (, not )

Comment: Well, I guess what I was mostly looking for is what could have caused this to happen, malicious or otherwise.